# How can I multiply the score of two queries together in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance, function-query

In Solr I can use the `query` function query to return a numerical score for a query and I can user that in the context of a `bf` parameter something like `bf=product(query('cat'),query('dog'))` to multiply two relevance scores together.

Elasticsearch has search API that is generally more flexible to work with, but I can't figure out how I would accomplish the same feat. I can use `_score` in a script_function of a function_query but I can only user the `_score` of the main query. How can I incorporate the score of another query? How can I multiply the scores together?

Comment: even better you can name those queries and do anything you want with them in the context of Solr's query DSL, such as `catQuery={!edismax qf=title^10 text v=$q}` then refer to that query in a function query: `product($catQuery...)`. Disappointed Elasticsearch lacks this fairly powerful capability

Answer (score 2):

You could script a TF*IDF scoring function using a `function_score` query.  Something like this (ignoring Lucene's query and length normalization):

```
"script": "tf = _index[field][term].tf(); idf = (1 + log ( _index.numDocs() / (_index[field][term].df() + 1))); return sqrt(tf) * pow(idf,2)"
```

You'd take the product of those function results for 'cat' and 'dog' and add them to your original query score.

Here's the full query [gist](https://gist.github.com/peterdm/9e31be343a733c44ff0e).

Comment: And there is a bevy of other index-level information you can use to test out and construct your own scoring script directly in the DSL:  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/modules-advanced-scripting.html

Comment: pretty awesome answer... but I would hop to avoid this type of low level detail. Especially if I'm thinking about a multiterm or multifield query.  The `function_score`'s `function`s supports a `filter` section. Ideally we could also just have a `query` section.

Comment: Or even simpler, add a `score_mode` argument to the `should` block of a `Bool Query`.   (As of now, ES scores boolean queries like this:  `must` clause score + sum-of(`should` clause scores)).  What you're trying to do is `must` clause score + prod-of(`should` clause scores).

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if you've got something in that `bf` that's heavyweight enough you'd rather not run it across the entire set of matches, you could use [rescore requests](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/search-request-rescore.html) to modify the score of the **top N ranked `ORIGINAL QUERY` results** using subsequent scoring passes with your (cat, dog, etc...) scoring-queries.

Comment: why did you answer the same question twice? If you wish to present an alternative solution you can add it into the same answer

Comment: I like having two different answers presented as two different answers so that the upvotes can differentiate between them